Can't wrap my head around an impersonal "se" example
I've been researching the use cases for "se", and regarding uses of the impersonal variant, I came across the following examples. In the bottom two, I have added (in parens) what I believe would be the quasi-equivalent in English, but don't understand if there's a reasonable translation for the first example.
“Se renta departamento amueblado.”
-> Furnished apartment for rent.
    
“Se reparan lavadoras y refrigeradores.”
-> (We) Fix washing machines and refrigerators.

“Se pica la carne en cuadritos.”
-> (You) Chop the meat into squares.

My questions... Do I have the bottom two translated reasonably, and what is the "se" referring to in the first example? Is it simply "We rent a furnished apartment"?

It's worth noting that some English speakers use the impersonal "one" instead of "you".  As in "One chops the meat into squares."

Another example might be "se habla español".

"One"... that's awesome insight... thanks @WalterMitty!

You can also turn some of  them into a passive. Washing machines and refrigerators repaired here. Furnished apartment for rent is also similar to a passive. The construction is super-common, signs say Se vende (casa) or Se aquila (casa) are everywhere.

I agree with mdewey, "Se reparan lavadoras" is something that you can see in a store window. Like "Se busca camarero" in a bar or restaurant, whose equivalent is "Help wanted: Waiter" or something like that. "We fix washing machines" in Spanish is "Reparamos lavadoras". Can you see the difference?

Languages do their own thing. This is one of them and you just have to learn it.  And in terms of translation, none of those take one in English. Se habla español [on signs in window shops in the States.] But in a Spanish-speakling country, you'd see: Se habla inglés. En Inglaterra, se come mucho pan tostado.

“Se renta departamento amueblado.”
“Se reparan lavadoras y refrigeradores.”
“Se pica la carne en cuadritos.”
All three are examples of the "se"-passive which, unlike the passive with the verb "ser", cannot take the agent and does sound impersonal.
The translations are perfect but, grammar-wise, it would be more accurate to say:

A furnished apartment is rented.

Washing machines and refrigerators are fixed (here).

The meat is chopped in cubes.


Grammatically speaking, the sentences are passive because, if the subject were plural (as is the case with "lavadoras y refrigeradores"), a plural verb would be used.
Here you can find more information as to when that "se" is passive and when impersonal.
“Se rentan departamentos amueblados.” -> Furnished apartments are rented.
“Se pican los trozos de carne en cuadritos.” The pieces of meat are chopped into cubes.

For the last one I would have said
"The meat is chopped into squares"
as an instruction.
For the other two I agree - they refer to an unknown person offering a service.

I was reading about the “passive voice” in Spanish and all I can tell you is that nobody has agreed if it is indeed that or if it exists or anything.
But what I can tell you is: -se renta cuarto amueblado- that’s technically erroneous. Why? Very simple, in Spanish (just as in English) you need a subject performing the action, and indeed you have it, however does it make sense to you that a room will rent itself? or the owner of the room -or the house- is the one renting it.
